Skew One Corner And Add Border Radius To Opposite Corner with gradient
How can I make this design in CSS?
enter image description here
I've tried everything, but the gradient of the pseudo element overlaps the main text.
 span {
    border: 2px solid #FFC402;
    border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
    padding: 6px;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #7a6bac 20%, #e83680 100%);
    position:relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

span:after{
      content:"";
      width: 15px;
      height:90%;
      position:absolute;
      right:-8px;
      top:-2px;
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, #7a6bac 20%, #e83680 100%);
       transform: skew(-20deg);
       border-top: 2px solid #FFC402;
       border-right: 2px solid #FFC402;
       box-sizing: border-box
}


after tinkering around with your code for a bit, this seems to work. you will have to fiddle around with the gradient to make it continue on without the weird break, and honestly it would probably be easier to just use a image, but still. if i'm interpreting your ask correct, its as simple as adding a bit of padding-right and making the height take up 105% instead of 90 :
           span {
              border        : 2px solid #FFC402;
              border-radius : 15px 0px 0px 15px;
              padding       : 6px;
              font-size     : 18px;
              display       : inline-block;
              background    : linear-gradient(90deg, #7a6bac 20%, #e83680 100%);
              position      : relative;
              box-sizing    : border-box;
              padding-right : 15px;
            }
            span:after{
              content      : "";
              width        : 15px;
              height       : 105%;
              position     : absolute;
              right        : -8px;
              top          : -2px;
              background   : linear-gradient(90deg, #7a6bac 20%, #e83680 100%);
              transform    : skew(-20deg);
              border-top   : 2px solid #FFC402;
              border-right : 2px solid #FFC402;
              box-sizing   : border-box
            } 

 <span>T</span>


Good. Where can I use the image here? The gradient itself or the whole block? The whole block will fail due to the size and the entire layout will break :(

oh, i was just saying that it would be easier to make a png with the thing youre trying to emulate rather than using a finnicky html && css element for it! it should be fine to do in html and css if you have the patience of a saint, but merely taking the image you referenced and resizing && using that instead of making an entire element for all the stuff would be simpler, i think.

it isnt necessary though. feel free to use the code i offered to do it instead :0) !
